# Is It Possible To Change the Date of Creation of a File (Docx, Pdf, jpg) from the Command Line?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

Let's say I would like to change the date of creation of a file (specially docx, pdf) to back in the past. Is it possible to do this from the terminal.

Comment: `touch -t <desireddate> <file>` will change date

Answer (score 4):

touch -t

from `man touch` the format is as follows

> -t STAMP
>             use [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.ss] instead of current time

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/man1/touch.1.html

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   touch file
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   touch -t 7001012005 file
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   stat file
  File: file
  Size: 0               Blocks: 16         IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 37h/55d Inode: 574182      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/ guiverc)   Gid: ( 1000/ guiverc)
Access: 1970-01-01 20:05:00.000000000 +1000
Modify: 1970-01-01 20:05:00.000000000 +1000
Change: 2019-06-04 22:46:02.178960273 +1000
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change the creation date of the file. The creation time is not even shown in the `stat`-command: `Birth: -`. The touch command changed `Access` and `Modify` times. The creation date is a bit special, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file

Comment: Yep.  I see on a search "*There is no way that creation time (btime) and change time(ctime) can be faked.  The only trick i could suggest you is to put back your system data, touch the file then get back "in the future*".  (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336298/how-to-change-files-creation-time-touch-changes-only-modified-time)

Comment: Also "*there is no creation time, there are only access, modify, and change dates. The POSIX standard only defines three distinct timestamps to be stored for each file: the time of last data access, the time of last data modification, and the time the file status last changed. Linux does not provide a kernel API for accessing the file creation times, even on filesystems supporting them (ext4, Btrfs and JFS), perhaps it will be impelemented in the future.*"  (from same reference)